# RedirectToAction Redirecting to Non matching MapRoute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two map routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RawMode",
    url: "raw/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, rawmode="1" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, rawmode = "0" }
);
```

The first route check for presence of "raw" word as part of url to enable raw mode of application. It all works fine. However, when I use `RedirectToAction("Index","Home")` in some URL say `http://domain/Home/TestPage`, it always take me to `raw` mode of application detecting the first `MapRoute` in sequence. i.e. to `http://domain/raw/Home/Index` rather than `http://domain/Home/Index`.

If I try to reverse the order of my map route, indeed `rawmode` didn't work when called directly in browser like `http://domain/raw/Home/Index` which is needed as well. How can I ensure that `RedirectToAction` redirect to `rawmode` only if I am `rawmode` page and not in general view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `return RedirectToRoute("Default")` it will redirect you to

```
 http://domain/Home/Index
```

Comment: ah, I miss that function, but that means when I have to redirect to `rawmode` I have to change the name of "Default" to correct maproute name. Well not what I like, want it automatic, but still good option.